# Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'LCB.Code.cuentaBanco.agregar(float)' 27 ACB

Tags: c#

```
namespace LCB.Code
{
    public class cuentaBanco
    {
        string nombre;
        float cuenta;

        public cuentaBanco(string nombre, float cuenta)
        {
            this.nombre = nombre;
            this.cuenta = cuenta;
        }

        public void agregar(float incrementar)
        {
            this.cuenta += incrementar;
        }

        public void remover(float remover)
        {
            if (remover >this.cuenta)
            {
                this.cuenta = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                this.cuenta -= remover;
            }
        }
    }
}


using LCB.Code;    
namespace ACB
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = cuentaBanco.agregar(float.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*An instance of an object is required* this means that you cannot call a NON STATIC method of a class without having declared and initialized an instance of that class. So you have two options. Make the agregar method static or initialize an instance of the cuentaBanco class. I really suggest to stay away from static methods unless you have a clear reason to condivide the method between many instances of your class and in your code I can't see any reason to have a static method. So I am going for the other option.
Make an instance of the cuentaBanco class...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cuentaBanco cuenta = new cuentaBanco("ABC", 0f);
    label1.Text = cuenta.agregar(float.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
}
```

but now we have another problem. The `agregar` method is declared as void. It means that it doesn't return anything. So you can't apply a ToString() to a void returning method.
You need also change the `agregar` method to return the calculated value

```
public class cuentaBanco
{
    ....

    public float agregar(float incrementar)
    {
        this.cuenta += incrementar;
        return this.cuenta;
    }
    ....
}
```

Again, looking at your class it seems that you want to have an object that keeps your counting and increment the internal number for every click on your button. In this case you want to keep a global object for your counting and  declare and initialize a class level variable of type cuentaBanco at the initialization of your form. Now you can use that variable to make your countings

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private cuentaBanco cuenta;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cuenta = new cuentaBanco("ABC", 0f);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = cuenta.agregar(float.Parse(textBox1.Text)).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make method `agregar` static.
Also after making `agregar` static you should make `cuenta` static too. Also the `agregar` method is `void` you can't set it to `label1.Text` you should change it's return type yo `float`:

```
static float _cuenta;

public static float agregar(float incrementar)
{
    _cuenta += incrementar;
    return _cuenta;
}
```

Also in the `cuentaBanco` method remove the `this` keyword and set a valid name instead of `cuenta` like `_cuenta`:

```
public cuentaBanco(string nombre, float cuenta)
{
    this.nombre = nombre;
    _cuenta = cuenta;
}
```

Comment: Good catch. I didn't see that he's calling the 'agregar' function 'statically'. Another solution and maybe better is to make an instance variable in 'Form1' of 'cuentaBanco'.

Comment: Because I don't think making the 'agregar' function static is the answer. @Steve 's answer is more likely to be what the OP is wanting who simply doesn't understand about class instances yet.  To somewhat counter the downvote, I upvoted your question.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz ... Your reason for downvote is not acceptable because making the `agregar` method static is just a way for doing this. maybe is not the best solution but it is not incorrect. Downvote is for incorrect answers.

Comment: While your answer may get the code to compile and 'work', I don't believe it's a correct answer.

Comment: @user2946329, I upvote because I agree with you and find no reason to downvote here. Downvote should be for really bad try, yours is not. Some people really are to fast to downvote and just can't understand every aspect of a problem/solution